# React router param w browserhistory

Tags: express, reactjs, react-router

Edit: **Solution**: Having absolute paths in your script src(s). Ty QoP.

I am trying to pass in params in React-Router like so:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="profile/:name" component={Profile} />
```

My server looks like this:

```
app.get('*', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
});
```

Everything works until the user refreshes the page or when one directly inputs the url (.../profile/1). Curiously, it is changing my (index) to the param itself in my source.[image]

This problem disappears and everything works if I put `<base href="/">` in my index.html. `base href` however is being deprecated in react-router for some reason and I'd like a different solution.

Comment: what does your `index.html` look like?

Comment: [Jsbin index.html](http://jsbin.com/qokozipudu/1/edit?html)

Comment: have you tried using absolute paths e.g  `/bundle/main.js` instead of `./bundle/main.js` ?

Comment: Tried it but it still breaks

Comment: Wait sorry, it works; I was being an idiot. Thanks a lot!